# React-Native Problem with the react-native-render-html component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, react-native-render-html

I try to use the react-native-render-html.

Here is my component:

```
import { memo, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'
import RenderHTML from 'react-native-render-html'

function TokenDetail({ navigation, token }) {
  // console.log('tokenDetail token:', token?.name)

  const test = 'Hello World'

  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      title: token.name
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    <View style={{ padding: 40 }}>
      <Text style={{ fontWeight: 600, paddingBottom: 20 }}>{token.symbol.toUpperCase()} - {token.name}</Text>
      <Text>{token.description.en}</Text>
      <RenderHTML source={token.description.en} />
    </View>
  )
}

export default memo(TokenDetail)
```

If I use this

```
<RenderHTML source={token.description.en} />
```

I get an error: No source prop was provided. But token.description.en it's OK because I have the result in my App in a Text field.

If I use this

```
<RenderHTML source={test} />
```

I got a new error: You should always pass contentWith prop.

But if I look on a doc, it's not required and when I try I got a new error in the editor :/

Please I would like to understand this. Thank you.

I read the doc, search with Google, but I do not understand the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you're still having this issue, I am trying to implement the same library. For me the problem was that I was passing the HTML string directly to the `source` prop, when instead it should be an object:

```
<RenderHTML source={{ html: yourHtmlString }} />
```